# Where on my system are the current/original maps stored for Starcraft 2?

Tags: starcraft-2

I would like to either edit current maps to increase the money on them, or get money maps.

Where, on my Windows 7 system, can I find the original Blizzard maps? Or are they not stored on my system?

Also where can I get good money maps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think they are stored anywhere accessible by default; however, you can follow this process to edit them:

1. Open SC2 map editor
2. Choose "open"
3. Choose the "battle.net" tab
4. Make sure the "blizzard" source is selected, then choose whatever map you want
5. Click OK

The map is now loaded in the editor - you can proceed to edit it and save it locally wherever you want.

Notice the editor has to be logged in to battle.net in order to do that, there's a "log in" button in that very menu that you can click if you're not already logged in.

Comment: I would recommend copying the map else where too, so blizz doesn't stomp on your changes

Comment: Love this response. The only follow-up question now is, how do I actually play the map I created?

Comment: @marc you can treat them like any other map, i.e. you can click the "test map" button to launch sc2 with them, or save them as a map file to distribute.

Comment: @Oak yeh but how do we play with with our friends and stuff online??